# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out while accessing remote database, logs show a connection was attempted

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently writing a web service that will receive a POST request and write the data to a database that is hosted on a different server. When running the script to  a database on the same server, it behaves as expected. However, once it tries to access the remote database the connection times out with that error.

I've read a lot of the answers that refer to configuring MySQL to allow remote root connections, but we've created a user with all privileges from any host.

The server logs of the MySQL database show that the user we created attempted to access the database but didn't use a password even though the password is programmed to be entered. I do not have access to the core MySQL files at this time.

Could it still be an issue with root remote access or the firewall even though the server log shows an attempt to connect to the database?

This is the PHP function that throws the error:

```
function webservice_db_connect() {
    try {
        global $db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port;
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_servername;dbname=$db_name;port=$db_port", $db_username, $db_password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $db;
    } catch(PDOException $error) {
        exit('Connection failed: '. $error->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Final Result:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

Comment: Did you var_dump() the db_username and db_password and make sure they aren't empty?

Comment: That sounds more like an access issue. Are you sure the server is allowing requests to the mysql port? `3306`

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database from the command line? if you're able to do that then your code should be able to do that no matter what unless there is an error in the code.

Comment: `global` is really a bad idea. Why would you need this data for any other function?

Comment: Yes, var_dump() returns all of the values. There are a few different files that are going to use those values, so I put them in one file. I can set them in the function instead. We can get into the database through MySQL Workbench on 3306

Comment: Can you connect to the DB using `mysql` commandline from your webserver? Or even establish a TCP connection using netcat?

Comment: Windows CLI failed when pinging the server, but it responded with Telnet. I don't have root access to the database, or the MySQL CLI at the moment. The last thing we did was enable global privileges on all schemas followed by flushing the privileges and restarting the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by trying to log into the remote mySQL server from the mysql client:

```
mysql -h your.remoteserver.com -p 3345 -u yourusername -p yourpassword
```

Try different usernames for a successful connection.

Did you reload the privileges on the remote mySQL database?

Comment: Thank you for this. We figured out that MySQL was changing the casing of the password. Running a query to store the password in the database revealed it.